# How to make the textarea height expand to loaded content?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I want the height of an editable `textarea` tag to be adjusted to the lines of text.

I tried to set the `rows` attribute to `1` on the `textarea`, to have have the default height if there's no text or only one line of text - but the textarea doesn't adjust in height automatically when there's more lines of text.

I'm not looking for expanding height while writing, I'm mainly concerned on page load.

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954252/css-textarea-that-expands-as-you-type-text

Comment: is simply setting it via JS on page load not an option?

Comment: Ah ok, so it's not possible with only HTML/CSS?

Comment: this is a duplicate of this question >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954252/css-textarea-that-expands-as-you-type-text

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to dynamically adjust height of textarea with only HTML/CSS.