# Expanding Textbox, Needs Margin or Counter Page Move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an expanding textbox that works "just fine."

I am using code from this thread:[CSS Textarea that expands as you type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954252/css-textarea-that-expands-as-you-type-text)
This is the code I am using:

```
$('textarea').on('paste input', function () {
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > this.scrollHeight){
        $(this).height(1)
    }
    while ($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))){
        $(this).height($(this).height() + 1)
    }
});
```

1) My issue is if there are many commnets and the textbox is close to the bottom... the actual type line/area is too low. It's pratically at the brower's bottom edge. So the first goal is to have the lowest type line/area/cursor, ~40px above the edge.

[image]

2) Another related issue is even if I scroll back to type, the minute a key is pressed the page scrolls, result: the line/cursor back to the very bottom.

An idea i have is expand the textbox but move the page up by a line to compensate for the textbox expansion. Line per line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I did exactly as thought and moved the window one font line down to compensate for the textbox expansion. My font size is 12px, so I move the window 12px. Resulting code is 1 additional line:

```
tbxComments.on('paste input', function () {
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > this.scrollHeight) {
        //alert('inside');
        $(this).height('64')
    }
    while ($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
        $(this).height($(this).height() + 1);
        **window.scrollBy(0, 12);**
    }
});
```

I hope that helps someone else!