# How to make a text area grow higher and wider to fit new text

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, textarea

I have a textarea for a code editor and therefore have intentionally set it to not wrap. Now, when the user types more text than fits in the textarea, the textarea will get a scrollbar. I do ***not*** want this behavior. Instead, I want the textarea to grow in *both* the x **and** y direction to accommodate the new text. I'm currently using the following code:

```js
function textarea_height(textarea, MaxHeight) {
    let textareaRows = textarea.value.split("\n");
    if (textareaRows[0] != "undefined" && textareaRows.length < MaxHeight) counter = textareaRows.length;
    else if (textareaRows.length >= MaxHeight) counter = MaxHeight;
    else counter = 1;
    textarea.rows = counter;
    let longest = textareaRows.reduce((acc, val) => val.length > acc.length ? val : acc);
    textarea.cols = longest.length;
}
```

which I have applied to the `input`, `change`, `keydown`, and `keyup` listeners. This code works perfectly for the height, but the width is a bit strange. For the first few columns of overflow, but the text area still gets a scrollbar. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This comment might help you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954751/10914325

Comment: @AnnaAzzam Good idea, but I don't use jQuery... :(