# Editable table cell with the least side effect

Tags: html, html-table, cell, edit

I would like to make a table cell editable such that it looks and feels like you're really editing the cell content and not the content of some element within the table cell.

Specifically, I would like to:

- not see any visual effects of elements other than the table cell element
- be able to click anywhere within the cell and start typing text (irrespective of how tall or wide the editable cell may be made by other cells in the table)
- not have to specify any absolute heights or widths
- have the text being edited contribute to the table row and column dimensions the same way that the content of non-editable cells does

I can place anything I want within the TD element and using JavaScript would be fine, but the HTML table structure is given to me by the framework I use.

My best guess so far would be to place a textarea into the table cell, make its border invisible and use  [CSS Textarea that expands as you type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954252/css-textarea-that-expands-as-you-type-text), but modify its size calculation to somehow take into account adjoining table cell heights. Is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click dogs and edit away.

```html
<table>
  <td contenteditable style="border: 1px solid black; outline: 0px;">dogs</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that works. I was somehow stuck on the idea that I could not change the TD elements themselves as they are generated by the framework. But I can add the contenteditable attribute using JavaScript after the page load.