# How to automatically expand the height of a textarea from bottom to top

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am currently creating a chatbox, and I want my input Textarea to automatically expand its height as users are typing just like that of the messenger app.

I am stuck now with a fixed height because when I set its max height the user needs to scroll down to see their typing.

BTW, I used tailwindcss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Textarea that expands as you type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954252/css-textarea-that-expands-as-you-type-text)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct way of doing this with `textarea` because Whatsapp chat and youtube comment themselves don't use `textarea` ! insead they use `div` with `contenteditable="true"`

```css
      body{
        background-color: hsl(222, 22%, 12%);
      }
      .input-box{
        width: 200px;
        height: max-content;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        outline: none;
        background: hsl(222, 22%, 20%);
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 1rem;
        right: 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      }

      .input-box:hover{
        border-color: hsl(222, 22%, 30%);
      }

      .input-box:focus{
        border-color: hsl(222, 22%, 40%);
      }
```

```html
<div class="input-box" contenteditable="true"></div>
<!-- only the above line does the job I put the just for looking good -->
```